# Не срабатывает select OnChange

Tags: javascript, jquery

Добрый день. Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу проверить. На входе имеем следующую форму калькулятора:

```
<FORM Name="myform" class="calcform">
    <SELECT NAME="width" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="width">
        <OPTION value="20">20 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="30">30 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="40">40 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="50">50 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="60">60 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="70">70 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="80">80 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="90" style="display: inline-block;">90 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="100" style="display: inline-block;">100 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="110" style="display: inline-block;">110 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="120" style="display: inline-block;">120 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="130" style="display: inline-block;">130 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="140" style="display: inline-block;">140 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="150" style="display: inline-block;">150 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="160" style="display: inline-block;">160 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="170" style="display: inline-block;">170 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="180" style="display: inline-block;">180 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="190" style="display: inline-block;">190 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="200" style="display: inline-block;">200 см.</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    <SELECT NAME="height" onChange="calculatePrice()" id="height">
        <OPTION value="20">20 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="30">30 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="40">40 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="50">50 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="60">60 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="70">70 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="80">80 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="90" style="display: inline-block;">90 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="100" style="display: inline-block;">100 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="110" style="display: inline-block;">110 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="120" style="display: inline-block;">120 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="130" style="display: inline-block;">130 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="140" style="display: inline-block;">140 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="150" style="display: inline-block;">150 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="160" style="display: inline-block;">160 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="170" style="display: inline-block;">170 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="180" style="display: inline-block;">180 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="190" style="display: inline-block;">190 см.</OPTION>
        <OPTION value="200" style="display: inline-block;">200 см.</OPTION>
    </SELECT>

    Стоимость:
    <INPUT value="0" disabled="disabled" type="text" id="PicExtPrice" Size=8>грн.
</FORM>
```

Не получается реализовать код, чтобы при выборе в первом `SELECT` с `id="width"`, `option` с `value > 80` - во втором `SELECT` с `id="height"` все `option` с `value > 80` прятать. И соответственно наоборот.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("select").on("change", function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id');

  if ((id == 'height')) {
    if ($("#height option:selected").val() > 80) {
      $("#width option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val > 80) {
          $(this).hide();
        }
        if ($("#width option:selected").val() > 80) {
          if ($(this).val() == '80') {
            $(this).prop("selected", 'selected');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#width option").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
      });
    }
  }

  if ((id == 'width')) {
    if ($("#width option:selected").val() > 80) {
      $("#height option").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() > 80) {
          $(this).hide();
        }
        if ($("#height option:selected").val() > 80) {
          if ($(this).val() == '80') {
            $(this).prop("selected", 'selected');
          }
        }
      });
    } else {
      $("#height option").each(function() {
        $(this).show();
      });
    }
  }
});
});
```

Проблема в том, что скрипт работает только для первого селекта, если во втором выбрать значение > 80, то в первом ни один OPTION не будет прятаться.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А, пардон:

```
  $("#width option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).val > 80) { // missing () after val
```